# Reorder fields using bibtex-mode

Tags: latex, sorting, bibtex

I would like to clean up BibTeX entries so that fields always appear in the same order.

For example, I would like the order of fields to always be: author, year, title, journal.  So, pressing `C-c C-q` on:

```
@Article{Smit90,
  title = {The Title},
  year = 1990,    
  author = {Smith, J.},
  journal = {The Journal}
}
```

Should produce:

```
@Article{Smit90,
  author = {Smith, J.},
  year = 1990,    
  title = {The Title},
  journal = {The Journal}
```

}

`bibtex-mode` has many options to reformat and clean up fields (see http://www.jonathanleroux.org/bibtex-mode.html#0620), but does not seem to have a way to reorder fields.  Ideally, the order of fields should be controlled from `bibtex-entry-format` and follow the order of fields that is defined in `bibtex-BibTeX-entry-alist`.

How could this be done?

Comment: I think you meant `C-c C-c` (bibtex-clean-entry) and not `C-c C-q` (bibtex-fill-entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `sort-fields` to `bibtex-entry-format`.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know about that option (it wasn't in the manual I linked in the question).  Thanks!